# Open Intent in a new context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

When I open a link inside the Facebook app, it opens a new task for the browser while I can switch back to the Facebook app instead of opening the browser inside itself like an ordinary Activity. But when I launch an Intent to my application's Google Play page it behaves like an Activity inside my app instead of launching a separate instance for Google Play.

Here's how I'm starting the Intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=MY.APP.PACKAGE")));
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832074/open-browser-as-intent-but-dont-keep-it-on-the-activity-stack) and wrote this snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=MY.APP.PACKAGE"));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(i);
```

Which fails with this message in logcat:

```
04-29 12:35:42.681: E/AndroidRuntime(8482): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] dat=market://details?id=MY.APP.PACKAGE flg=0x50000000 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the `addCategory()` call and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to flag your answer as accepted, sorry :)